# Generate custom classes from within a security sandbox (e.g., applet)

Tags: java, security, applet, classloader, securitymanager

I'd like to be able to generate and load custom classes within an (unsigned) applet. Generating them I can deal with, but I'm battling with the applet SecurityManager that doesn't seem to want me to load them.

Here's a visual overview; as you can see I'm stuck on Phase 2:

[image: underpants gnomes]

What I originally intended was to use a custom class loader. Apparently this isn't allowed in an applet; the ClassLoader constructor throws a SecurityException.

Then I considered calling [ClassLoader.defineClass(String name, byte[] b, int off, int len)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#defineClass%28java.lang.String,%20byte[],%20int,%20int%29) on another class loader directly, but that method is protected.

I tried to make the method accessible via reflection. My hopes there weren't high but I tried it and indeed that too threw a SecurityException.

[URLClassLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html) appeared to offer salvation: it has a static factory creation method which does not throw any security exception. However, that technique doesn't permit subclassing the loader or access to the protected defineClass method. It only accepts an array of URL objects.

So I tried to subclass [URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) to override its openConnection method to return my class bytes that way, but the URL class is final.

Then I tried creating a custom [URLStreamHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLStreamHandler.html) with an overridden openConnection method and passing it to the constructor of a URL. The SecurityManager threw another fit over this.

So then I tried calling URL.setStreamHandlerFactory with a custom factory that would return my custom stream handler. There was the SecurityManager again, complaining, because what else is it good for if not complaining?

So then I tried creating a [javax.management.loading.MLet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/management/loading/MLet.html). I have no clue what it's for but it's a subclass of URLClassLoader that allows specifying a custom URLStreamHandlerFactory in its constructor and doesn't mention throwing a security exception, but it still did anyway.

In desperation I tried calling [ProxySelector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ProxySelector.html).setDefault with a custom ProxySelector, hoping to incercept a URL and somehow route it back into my applet, but I don't have permission for that either.

I tried setting the `java.system.class.loader` property via a `<param name="java_arguments" ...>` tag, but it didn't seem to be one of the honored properties.

<strike>Finally, the only remaining way I can think of to do this is to send my class bytes up to a remote server that will generate a temporary URL that I can use in conjunction with URLClassLoader.newInstance(URL[]). That would work but I really don't like the idea. It seems like it could get complicated fast, with the interaction of the different ClassLoaders, and the server-dependence is not really practical for what I want to do.</strike> *Apparently the SecurityManager is only too happy to let you create a URLClassLoader, but gets spontaneously upset when you try to use it.*

I *would* like to do this from within the normal unsigned applet security sandbox if it's at all possible, so that the experience is seamless.

But mostly I'm just baffled, because if it's not possible it makes no sense. <strike>If the SecurityManager is happy about loading classes from arbitrary external URLs it shouldn't mind loading one from a byte array in a local variable.</strike> *The restriction is still nonsensical. The code is still internal and sandboxed.*

It's useful both for dynamic code generation and for implementing custom JAR compression, like LZMA compression.

Help!

Comment: *I'm battling with the applet SecurityManager that doesn't seem to want me to load them."*  I suspect the `AccessControlException` that results is pretty explicit, no 'seems' about it.  Why would I, as a sure, want to see this applet create new code and load it, within a sand-box?  **Sign the applet.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ..the SecurityManager again, complaining, because what else is it good for if not complaining?

It is there for the protection of the end user, against doing exactly the sorts of things you are attempting.

> ..how do I load the class?

Sign the Jar, get the user to accept the digitally signed code.

> ..send my class bytes up to a remote server that will generate a temporary URL that I can use in conjunction with URLClassLoader.newInstance(URL[]).

A sand-boxed applet cannot create an `URLClassLoader`.

Comment: The question is very obviously, how do I load the class? As I pointed out with the remote server example there is absolutely no security advantage to preventing it.

Comment: As an aside, no matter how pure your intentions are, if you find a way to do this from within the security sand-box, it is a ***security bug***!

Comment: So it's not possible? But why? What difference could it possibly make?

Comment: I am not a security expert.  I just know the JRE will not permit any number of things in a sand-boxed applet.  E.G. Reflection, file I/O, dynamically loading classes..

Comment: That's disappointing. I'm feeling a bit grumpy about it but I'll accept your answer. It's not your fault this silly restriction exists.

Comment: I have been similarly frustrated in the past when doing the same types of (seemingly innocuous) things.  I try to be philosophical about it: 1) The Java plug-in does not work if it is not installed. 2) If it is full of security holes, the users will not install it.